Cartoon episode where the main character grows large amounts of hair eventually turning into a monster
I remember watching two episodes of a cartoon at a friends house in the mid to late-2000s, most likely on German Nickelodeon.
The story of the first episode was about the main character getting a new haircut, long curly hair. Maybe this character normally doesn't have any significant hair? Not sure about that. His new hair then wouldn’t stop growing and eventually transformed into a city-threatening monster. I think it was stopped after getting wet in a pool and loosing its curls.
The second episode was about a parade with huge wagons, but the main characters' wagon had just a small scooter underneath. I think it had the shape of an elephant, but I'm not sure about that. Eventually the wagon collapsed.
At first, I was convinced the show was Rocko's Modern Life, but I’m not sure anymore because I couldn’t find any episodes with this plot. It could have very well been a rerun of a '90s show.

Checking the list of examples of "Rapid Hair Growth" on TV Tropes didn't turn up any promising results (obligatory warning: massive time sink)
